# Begginner programmer having trouble with for statements

Tags: javascript

here is the code I was creating on Treehouse and i'm stuck. I'm not sure why it isn't displaying on the preview. I linked the file in the index.html correctly and that didn't do anything. The end result is supposed to have circles with numbers in them but it wont display anything. any help would be appreciated thank you .

```
var html = '';


for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i += 1; ) {
  html += "<div>" + i + "</div>"  ;
}

document.write(html);
```

Comment: How did you link the file in your HTML?

Comment: Remove the last semi-colon in `var i = 1; i <= 10; i += 1; `

Comment: Wrong flag imo, should be the simple typographical error

Comment: @deceze I'd close this as off-topic due to a typo, not because it's missing code (which is seems to have)

Comment: @j08691 Could be a typo, could be a problem in the way the code is "linked". Hard to tell.

Comment: @deceze mmmm, not really. Seems like a clear case of an errant `;`

Comment: Learn to open browser console (F12) to check if code throws errors. Code shown throws a syntax error and tells you where. Then there are online javascript code linters you can use for more specific details also

Comment: ok will do Im just getting used to this. and i edited my post. lol you guys take that stuff way too serious,but ill remember next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the last semi-colon (`;`) after `var i = 1; i <= 10; i += 1;`

If you press "F12" in your browser developer console will open. The console will give you some suggestions.

```js
var html = '';

for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i += 1) {
  html += "<div>" + i + "</div>"  ;
}

document.write(html);
```

Comment: Also thanks for the advice

Comment: No problem, don't know about the down voting. If it fixed your problem. Could you accept my answer?

Comment: yea i def will thanks mike

Answer (score 0):

You have a extra semi-colon on your for loop. Try this:

```
var html = '';

for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i += 1) {
  html += "<div>" + i + "</div>";
}

document.write(html);
```